# I am having trouble with Excel 2010. When I use '1 to fill a column it repeats 1,2,3 then starts over with 1,2,3. I need it to continue with 3, 4, 5

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I get Excel 2010 to stop repeating 1,2,3?  I need '1 in my column because I need to leave some cells blank, but when I use'1 it only continues with 1, 2, 3 and then start over with 1 instead of 4.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

Try this: select cell **A2** and type formula `=MAX($A$1:A1)+1`

Stretch this cell down far enough.

Now select the cell you want to leave blank and clear it by pressing the **Delete** key.

[image: 1,2,3,,4,5]

Comment: Hi. The problem is not adding blanks.  It continues to repeat 1,2,3 when I use the apostrophe with the 1.   I need the apostrophe on all numbers but to continue 1,2,3,4,5.....instead of repeating the 1,2,3